# Tag incoming syslog messages with source?

Tags: osx-lion, syslogd

I'm running Mac OS X 10.7 server, with syslogd accepting remote syslogs on the standard UDP port. I just spent some time trying to debug a problem where I was getting messages in my log every 10 seconds with no indication of where the messages were coming from. I was able to track them down by putting syslogd into debug mode (which then showed when it accepted a packet and where from), however it would (obviously) have been much simpler if the messages themselves had included the source IP. Is there a way to make syslog add this information to the messages it receives?